# How to manage approved pending field with two models in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django model called Authorized that has the `sales_item` foreignKey
How can authorized person approve or decline the sales with adding some comments on sale object if salesmen add new sale in database? i am not able to understand that where i can add the `approved or decline` attributes

**models.py**

```
class Authorize(models.Model):
    managers = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    sales_item = models.ForeignKey(Sale, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    comments = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class Sale(models.Model):
    saler = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    customers = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a One-to-One relationship of Sale table with Authorize table.

```
class Authorize(models.Model):
    managers = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    sales_item = models.ForeignKey(Sale, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    comments = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    sale = models.OneToOneField(
        Sale,
        primary_key=True,
        db_column="id",
        parent_link=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

There is status field in each table. Use status in Authorize table for storing status and comments for approval.

Comment: what about the `sales_item` ForeignKey